# Quick Implicit Differentiation Question: tangent line to $\sin^{-1}(2x^2+y^2)=\frac2x+y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given the following prompt:

> find the slope of the line tangent to the curve $\sin^{-1}(2x^2+y^2)=\frac2x+y^2$

Is all that it's asking for an implicit differentiation? I don' think the actual implicit differentiation part would be all that hard, but I'm confused on the wording of the question. A little guidance on the differentiation would be helpful too!

Comment: Do they ask you to find the slope at a certain point on the curve?

Comment: Nope, they're asking for the slope of the tangent line to the entire function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the interpretations of the wording that the comments have provided. I have provided a solution

Taking the derivative wrt to x on both sides gives us $\frac{4x+2yy'}{\sqrt{1-(2x^2+y^2)^2}}=-\frac{2}{x^2}+2yy'$
$4x+2yy'=-\frac{2\sqrt{1-(2x^2+y^2)^2}}{x^2}+2yy'\sqrt{1-(2x^2+y^2)^2}$
$(2y-2y\sqrt{1-(2x^2+y^2)^2})y'=-\frac{4x^3+2\sqrt{1-(2x^2+y^2)^2}}{x^2}$

$y'=\frac{2x^3+\sqrt{1-(2x^2+y^2)^2}}{x^2y(\sqrt{1-(2x^2+y^2)^2}-1)}$

Comment: What this tells you is that if $(x,y)$ is a point on the curve, then the slope at that point is given by the expression @AlanAbraham gives. Note though that this value can be computed at _any_ point in the plane, not just points on the curve.

Comment: You are right @EthanDlugie. Usually with implicit differentiation problems you don't find y in terms of x explicitly and substitute into your expression for y'. Because of this, you have to first find a point $(x,y)$, that lies on the given curve, and then plug that coordinate into the expression for y' to find the slope of the tangent.